# Understand how DBMS executes IN query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, subquery

i had performance issue with my query, I found out solution, but i don't really understand why i had problem, so can someone explain me this...
I have 2 tables: Flow (few milion rows) and Devices (< 10 rows). Expected result of query was Latest row from Flow table for each device, plus data from Devices table.

My first query was:

```
SELECT * FROM Flow WHERE FlowId IN (SELECT MAX(FlowId) FROM Flow GROUP BY DeviceId)
```

Execution time > 200 seconds.

If I execute sub-query first (I get result in 0.01 second), and then use result in query:

```
SELECT * FROM Flow WHERE FlowId IN (93143922, 93143921)
```

I have result in less then a second... How DBMS executes first query ? I thought that flow is:
First execute sub-query, and then use result in "main" query ? If I do this steps manually, query is fast, so this absolutely is't how it works :(

My solution is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Flow f
INNER JOIN Devices d on d.DevicesId = f.DeviceId
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(FlowId) as FlowId FROM FLOW GROUP BY DeviceId) maxFlow
 ON maxFlow.FlowId = f.FlowId
```

But I need to know how it works with IN :)

Comment: How do you know which device belongs to which flow?

Comment: Start with EXPLAIN of every query

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

`IN` sometimes doesn't optimize well.  There are a few reasons for this:

- The results from the subquery need to be "deduped".  You may know there are no duplicates, but that is hard for the engine to know.
- It is hard for the engine to guestimate how many rows will be returned from the `IN`

I find that a correlated subquery often has the best performance:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM Flow f
WHERE f.FlowId = (SELECT MAX(f2.FlowId)
                  FROM Flow f2
                  WHERE f2.DeviceId = f.DeviceId
                 );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `Flow(DeviceId, FlowId)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your case will only happen for really bad optimizer or if the DB syntax over arbitrary field is not standard. Note that inside the IN clause, you put fields `FlowId` and `DeviceId`. By default, most optimisers can understand that is referring to the value of the constant table inside the IN clause, but some may think it is affected by the scope outside in, hence the details inside IN need to be re-evaluated per row of the outer scan.

Good optimiser:
 1. compute the result of IN
 2. loop through each row for the outer scan using the result of 2 / or seek the result from index if the `FlowId` is the first key of any index

Bad optimiser (or syntax limitation):
 1. loop through each row for the outer scan
 2. for each row, compute the result of IN
 3. compute the result of WHERE using the result of 2

The bad case is really bad as it full scans your table as many times as the number of rows in your table.